# How to change Background color in a Video? Software to be used are Filmora or Adobe Premier pro

Tags: color, background, video

I have a little video animation. I want to change the backgroud color (Part of built-in Video) from black to white throughout the whole video without disturbing the main focused logo (RED logo).

[image]

Comment: Video questions are generally best handled at http://video.stackexchange.com and are somewhat off-topic here -- but can't you simply change the stage color? Assuming you have an actual *video* construction files and not the gif you posted or a simple mp4, et. al. -- in which case I think you'd need to reconstruct from the ground up. The black is *integrated* into each and every frame of a gif or flat video file.

Comment: Well, i didn't know about the video.stackexchange.com was a thing. But, thank you for letting me know. I converted the mp4 file to image (.gif) as it was not allowing me to upload direct video file. And, surely will test the approach you shared.

Comment: If it's just an mp4, reconstructing entirely would be easier than removing the black.

Comment: Well, I am not the owner of this video. And i have not made it. I just got it in this state and being asked to change the black bg to white. That's why I asked. Yes, it would have been so much easy to made changes in it,  only if i have made it.